# Sqlite subquery with multiple sums

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a sqlite database and I need to perform some arithmetic in my sql to get the final amount. The thing is I am not certain how to go and achieve this, I'm pretty certain from what I've been reading its a subquery which I need to group by lineID (unique id in my db)

The fields I want to include in the calculation below are

```
el.material_cost1 * el.material_qty1
el.material_cost2 * el.material_qty2
el.material_cost3 * el.material_qty3
```

The query I currently have is below. It returns the value of my costs apart from the fields missing above. As I store the material costs individually, I can't work out how to do a subquery within my query to get the desired result.

```
SELECT sum(el.enquiry_cost1) + sum(el.enquiry_cost2) + sum(el.enquiry_cost3)
FROM estimate e
LEFT JOIN estimate_line el
ON e.estimateID=el.estimateID
WHERE e.projectID=7 AND el.optional='false'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `[INNER] JOIN` is pointless, as your `WHERE` condition filters out any rows that could have differed.

I think you're making this harder than it needs to be.  In particular, nothing in your description makes me think you need a subquery.  Instead, it looks like this query would be close to what you're after:

```
SELECT
  sum(el.enquiry_cost1)
  + sum(el.enquiry_cost2)
  + sum(el.enquiry_cost3)
  + sum(el.material_cost1 * el.material_qty1)
  + sum(el.material_cost2 * el.material_qty2)
  + sum(el.material_cost3 * el.material_qty3)
    AS total_costs,
FROM
  estimate e
  JOIN estimate_line el
    ON e.estimateID = el.estimateID
WHERE e.projectID = 7 AND el.optional = 'false'
```